# The article 'a' grammar

Tags: articles

> A woman's mind

Does the indefinite article here refer to the noun 'woman' or 'mind'?

Comment: It refers to *woman*.  Why?  Because even if the second noun were plural, like *arms*, you could still say "a woman's arms".  Or if it were non-count, like *flour*, you could say "a woman's flour".

Comment: Compare with "[a beautiful mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Beautiful_Mind_(film))" - here **beautiful** is an adjective, so the indefinite article refers to **mind**. In "a beauty's mind", the indefinite article would refer to **beauty**.

Comment: @stangdon What about _a children's song?_ What about _a women's movement?_ This is a deeper question than it first appeared (or my mind is shallower than it first appeared.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant - Very perceptive!  You're quite right.  Apparently it can refer to either one, and you may just have to tell from context.  This has turned out to be a surprisingly tricky question.

Comment: @stangdon The question is +5 and the best we have so far is "Maybe because "woman" needs an article itself." There must be an underlying principle here somewhere. Why don't you have a go? If not, I will. Then StoneyB or F⚡︎F will apply the coup de grace with a fifty-word explanation that makes perfect and obvious sense but which neither of us thought of.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think when a noun is used as an adjective, like here, additional adjectives modify the word that they come before.

For example, "a black woman's shirt". We probably mean that the woman is black, not that the shirt is black. If we meant that the shirt was black, we would say "a woman's black shirt".

You can also put commas between modifiers to indicate that they all apply to the final noun. "A black, woman's shirt" means that the shirt is black and it belongs to or is for a woman. But I've never seen this done with an article. Nobody write "a, woman's foot". Maybe because "woman" needs an article itself.

In any case, this isn't an absolute rule. When it's obvious from context what noun an adjective is modifying, you can deviate. Like if I read, "an orange woman's shirt", I would assume this means that the shirt is orange and not that the woman is orange.

Answer (score 1):

*A woman's mind* is an indefinite noun phrase. The  article does not refer to either *woman* or *mind* but to *woman's mind*.

Example: A woman's mind is sharp, a man's mind is  dull.